# Regex to capture numeric field

Tags: c#, regex

I am looking for a regular expression where i can extract portion of a string that meets the criteria.

string lookup "The length is 32.00 mm".

I would like to be able to get "32.00". Basically the first numeric value before " mm ". in a burte force kind of way, it can be done like this:

```
string test = "The length is 32.00 mm";

      int idx = test.IndexOf(" mm ") - 1;
      int endIdx = idx;
      while (idx > 0)
      {
        Char c = test.ElementAt(idx);
        if (Char.IsDigit(c) == false && c != '.')
        {
          string data = test.Substring(idx + 1, endIdx - idx + 1);
          break;
        }
        idx--;
      }
```

Do you have any better logic?

I can split the string by space and pick up the entry before the "mm" slot.

Thanks,

Comment: Depending on how precise it must be - even `[\d.]+(?=\s+mm)` might satisfy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can use regex with positive lookahead

```
\s[\d.]+(?=\s+mm)
```

Like this

```
string test = "The length is 32.00 mm";
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Match(test, @"\s[\d.]+(?=\s+mm)").Value);
```

[**DEMO**](http://csharppad.com/gist/1820e7a9016c0cf7d3d4)

Comment: It is close but it is matching those that don't have space between the digits and mm. 

"test cc 12.mm" and "test cc 12mm".

Comment: @Sam I've changed the regex.. Take a look now

Comment: @vks you're not seeing that I've used `Regex.Match` instead of `Matches` and the former only gives you the first match, as opposed to the latter. So your regex is a bit overkill

Comment: @Sam also, if you want just a single space after the number and before the `mm`, then use `[\d.]+(?= mm)`

Comment: Thanks for your quick feedback Amit. 

Almost there 

pattern.Match("test cc a12.0 mm"). This shouldn't match.

Comment: It is bringing a match. 

It shouldn't. 

The requirement it must be have 

Space NumericField Space mm  so. XXXX 13.99 mm should match but XXX13.99 mm shouln't. 

HOpe that helps

Comment: @EhsanSajjad I would suggest going through www.regular-expressions.info